# PDO/MySQL connection using MAMP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mamp

I'm trying to code a simple CMS but got stuck when doing the PDO connection getting the try/catch error. I'm quite sure the error comes from MAMP when using PDO but I have no idea how to fix it. The code I've wrote is the following:

includes/connection.php

```
<?php

try {
    $dbc = new PDO('myqsl:host=localhost;dbname=cms1', 'root', 'root');
} catch (PDOException $e){
    exit("Database error.");
}
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php

include_once('includes/connection.php');

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <a href="index.php">CMS</a>

        <ol>
            <li><a href="article.php?id=1">Article title</a> - <small>Posted 10th Jan</small></li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me.

Comment: What does the actual error say? Rather than hide it, show it: `catch(PDOException $e){exit($e->getMessage());}`

Comment: It would be useful if you included the error you are getting in your post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line contains a typo (if it isn't a typo):

```
$dbc = new PDO('myqsl:host=localhost
                ^^^^^
```

should read as:

```
$dbc = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost
```

Your `PDOException` should also include the *real* error message, instead of just "Database error":

```
catch(PDOException $e) { print $e->getMessage(); }
```

Including:

```
$dbc->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

right after the connection is opened.

---

*References:*

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using Laravel & MAMP:

You will also need to add the below to your code/controller (typically outside of your class).

use PDO;

example below:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\db_task_related\misc\pdo_related;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use PDO;

class pdo_test extends Controller
{
    public function run ()
    {
        
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "root";
        $dbname = "my_db";

        try {
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
            // set the PDO error mode to exception
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            echo "Connected successfully";
            $conn = null;
        } 
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
        }

    }
}
```

without 'use PDO;' in some cases you will recieve an error

for e.g:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\db_task_related\misc\column_checks\PDO' not found

Comment: Could you elaborate? Like why would someone need it? Can't this problem be solved with a db connection?

Comment: @DouwedeHaan I've just updated my answer with some more information. Let me know if it helps.